# Set visibility of button when user is in the last page of uipageviewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a viewcontroller `(FirstVC.swift)` with a container view, in the upper part, that has an embedded pageviewcontroller `(SecondPageVC.swift)`, and a view that has 3 buttons in the lower part.
At first, the only button visible is the middle button and other two is hidden. If the user reaches the last page, the other two buttons should appear. How do I pass the bool value that will make the buttons appear?

In my `SecondPageVC.swift`

```
 func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, 
    viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
  if index == myViewControllers.count-1{ //if last page
      hide = true
  }
```

Comment: So you want to pass your hide variable to your FirstVC ?

Comment: Yes. So my other two buttons will appear if user reached the last page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Define a protocol called PageDelegate like this :

`protocol PageDelegate { func hasReachLastPage(hasReached: Bool) }`

2. Create a delegate var in your SecondPageVC like this : `weak var delegate: PageDelegate?`
3. On your pageViewController func called your `func hasReachLastPage(hasReached: Bool)` like this :

   `func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, 
               viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
             if index == myViewControllers.count-1{ //if last page
                 delegate?.hasReachLastPage(true)
             }`
4. On your FirstVC makes it adopt your protocol that you just create like this : `FirstVC : PageDelegate`
5. Then, on your FirstVC when you have an instance of your SecondPageVC you are going to set your delegate variable to that FirstVC like this : `SecondPageVC.delegate = self`
   You are saying that FirstVC is going to handle SecondPageVC delegate methods
6. Finally always on your FirstVC you have to implement the body of `func hasReachLastPage(hasReached: Bool)` by hidding or not your two buttons like this :

   `func hasReachLastPage(hasReached: Bool) {
         if hasReached {
           // Unhide two buttons
         } else {
           // Hide buttons or whatever
         }
       }`

This is how you implement the **delegate pattern**. It's something very used and very useful to pass data between view controllers.

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understand correctly, you just want to pass this `hide` property to the instance of `FirstVC`? If so, I would advise you to define a protocol `SecondPageVCDelegate` with a method `secondPageVCDidReachLastPage:`. Assigning the delegate can be done in prepare for segue method of the `FirstVC`.